# Получить результат sql запроса с выводом больше 3 записей

Tags: sql

Плдскажите пожалуйста, есть 3 таблицы:

1) Cities
        
`| id     | name     |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | Москва   |
| 2      | Сочи     |`

2) Magaz

```
| id     | name     | adress        | city_id |
+--------+----------+---------------+---------+
| 1      | Магазин1 | ул. Ленина    | 1       |
| 2      | Магазин2 | ул. Мира      | 2       |
```

3) Cash

```
| id     | number   | description   | magaz_id |
+--------+----------+---------------+---------+
| 1      | 1        | касса 1       | 1       |
| 2      | 2        | касса 1       | 1       |
| 3      | 3        | касса 2       | 2       |
| 4      | 4        | касса 2       | 2       |
| 5      | 5        | касса 2       | 2       |
| 6      | 6        | касса 3       | 3       |
```

Помогите вывести список всех магазинов, в которых более 3х касс (cash), со столбцами [Магазин], [Город], [Адрес магазина]

```
SELECT magaz.name AS 'Магазин', cities.name AS 'Город', magaz.adress AS 'Адрес магазина' FROM magaz 
INNER JOIN cash ON magaz.id = cash.number JOIN cities ON cities.id = city_id ORDER BY magaz.name
```

знаю что нужно использовать Count но не знаю что куда, заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: *знаю что нужно использовать Count* И ещё GROUP BY. *не знаю что куда* Попробуйте почитать справку по группировкам и агрегатным функциям - там всё совершенно однозначно.

Comment: ага, спасибо за ответ